# Create Lead with Assignment-Rule via Apex does not work

Tags: apex, trigger, assignment-rules

I have a trigger on a custom object, that (as part of the functionality) creates leads.

I want the leads to be created and then assigned with the assignment rules in the current org, and I got that working on my sandbox in my regular tests and also when manually triggering the lead creation (on production).
However, when I import my objects via the API (Dataloader or WebImporter), the assignment rules do not run.

Here's the code I use:

```
Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;
for (Lead l : lsToInsert.values())
    l.setOptions(dmo);

Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(lsToInsert.values(), false);
```

Any idea, why?